# Enable XA Transactions through a batch file or script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, automation, msdtc

Im trying to create a batch file or a script that enables this option in Windows 7x64
The reason for this is that when running a silent installation I get en error pointing to this. If I do it manually all works fine.

Im not sure how to create this batchfile/script/powershell...?

Any ideas?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option 'sits' in the registry according to MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc224817.aspx

With PowerShell it will be like this:

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MSDTC\\Security\\" -Name "XaTransactions" -Value "1"
```

Note that you need admin rights. Tried it on Windows 8.

You may want to experiment with reading the value first - here's the way:

```
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MSDTC\\Security\\" -Name "XaTransactions"
```